# how to read array of hashes as input.txt file to sort in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is an array of hashes that i saved to input.txt file

```
arr_hash = [{"Name"=>"Aku","Email"="hello@gmail.com,"place"=>"abc"},
         {"Email"=>"xyz@gmail.com.com","place="India","Name"=>"Rocky"}
         {"place"=>"India","Email"=>"abc@gmail.com","Name"=>"Rocky"}]
```

below is a piece of code i tried reading an array of hashes from text file to sort (main.rb)

```
file = File.open("input.txt","r+")
sorted = file.map{|h| h.values_at(:Name, :place, :Email)}.sort
puts sorted
```

this is the code to generate a new file to display output

```
output_file = File.open("outputfile.txt","w" )
output_file << sorted
output_file.close
```

when i tried to read input.txt file to sort it accordingly,i got the error below

```
undefined method `values_at' for #<String:0x000055fac2499158> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Because when you read the file, it would return a string not an array of hashes

Comment: Save it as JSON or as CSV, it'll be easier to parse when you read it.

Comment: ^ YAML is already used a lot in the Ruby on Rails framework, so that would also be a good option.

Comment: **This is not a good solution**, but in order to achieve this in the way you're currently trying, you would need to run `eval` on the file. However, that's inefficient, wouldn't work between different languages, and (most importantly) opens a giant potential security hole with arbitrary code being executed.

Comment: So, tl;dr: LIke everyone else is saying already, don't try to store the raw ruby object; instead, store data in a well-defined standard format - such as CSV, YAML or JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Text file does not look like an appropriate choice to me. Instead, why don't you use JSON ?

You could define you file like so:

```json
{
  "1": {
    "Name": "Aku",
    "Email": "hello@gmail.com",
    "place": "abc"
  },
  "2": {
    "Email": "xyz@gmail.com.com",
    "place": "India",
    "Name": "Rocky"
  },
  "3": {
    "place": "India",
    "Email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "Name": "Rocky"
  }
}
```

Import it in Ruby like so:

```rb
require 'json'

file = File.read 'input.json'
data = JSON.parse file

data.class 
# => Hash

data.first
# => ["1", {"Name"=>"Aku", "Email"=>"hello@gmail.com", "place"=>"abc"}]

data.each_value { |value| puts value['Name'] }
# => Aku
# => Rocky
# => Rocky
```

And it's really easy to dump a Hash as JSON:

```rb
my_hash = {
  "Name"=>"Aku",
  "Email"=>"hello@gmail.com",
  "place"=>"abc"
}

File.write('output.json', JSON.dump(my_hash))
```

Comment: [`values_at`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/values_at) expects one or more keys as argument. I'm not sure to understand your request, does this snippet fits your need ?
`data.each_value.map { |hash| hash.values.join("\t") }.sort`